# Using VBScript script to detect and repair broken Powerpoint

Tags: script, microsoft-powerpoint, automation, vbscript

I have a .VBS script similar to this that loops through a folder and save the titleslides of PowerPoints

```
Dim InputFolder : InputFolder = "C:\........\"
Dim OutputFolder : OutputFolder = "C:\........\"
Dim ObjFolder : Set ObjFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject").GetFolder(InputFolder)

Dim Extension : Extension = "PNG"
Dim PixelWidth : PixelWidth = 1024
Dim PixelHeight : PixelHeight = 768

Dim ObjPPT : Set ObjPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Dim ObjSPresentation
Dim ObjSlide

For Each File In ObjFolder.Files
    if (File.Type = "Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation") Then

        ' Open PPT
        ObjPPT.Presentations.Open File
        Set ObjPresentation = ObjPPT.ActivePresentation

        ' Select title slide
        Set ObjSlide = ObjPresentation.Slides(1)

        ' Export slide
        ObjSlide.Export OutputFolder & ObjPresentation.Name & "." & Extension, _
            Extension, _
            PixelWidth, _
            PixelHeight

        ' Close PPT
        ObjPresentation.Close
    End If
Next

ObjPPT.Quit
```

It runs fine up until it reaches a particular file, when it throws the error:

```
C:\........\ppt.vbs(17,4) (null): Unspecified error
```

And when I open the presentation, I get this dialogue window

```
PowerPoint found a problem with content in C:\broken.pptx.
PowerPoint can attempt to repair the presentation.

If you trust the source of this presentation, click Repair.
```

Repairing it works fine. My question is whether or not I can have the script check for this every time and automatically Repair if necessary. To have to restart the script whenever a broken PPT file is found kind of defeats the purpose of the automation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `on error`.

So instead of:

`ObjPPT.Presentations.Open File`

try something like:

```
On Error Resume Next
ObjPPT.Presentations.Open File
If Err.Number <> 0 then
  'handle error opening file or emit log to handle manually etc
Endif
On Error Goto 0
```

You can also use labels and `goto` to jump to the end of the file loop, or you can simply put the rest of the loop inside a conditional where `Err.Number = 0`.

Check MS documentation for details or see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317840/understanding-on-error-in-vbscript

Comment: Of course this presumes that the error is handle-able, it may not be depending on the object.